# Journey Builder error on Multi Org

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud, multi-org

I have 2 business units connected to the same org and 2 Journeys with the same entry event (Salesforce event : created or updated on the Contact object)

I can see new entries on both Journeys but encountered below error:

> Error element
>   SalesforceObjeaef6410676db083d1e033001c3bbdb0_FireJBTrigger
>   (FlowActionCall). An Apex error occurred: System.LimitException:
>   et4ae5:Too many queueable jobs added to the queue: 2

What is the impact of this and how to deal with the error?

Comment: Can you comment if this just started occurring, or has it always been this way?

Comment: Never encountered this before. It started just after activating the new Journey in the different BU. Alerts arrive via email on every entry...